# Hosmer-Lemeshow error

Tags: r

This is probably a simple coding issue but I can't for the life of me get it.
Using this code for a logit:

```
glm(formula = cbind(Found, Missing) ~ Male + Age, family = binomial, 
    data = table.5.15)
```

I can't get the Hosmer-Lemeshow to work:

```
hosmerlem(miss.logit$cbind(Found,Missing), fitted(miss.logit))

Error in cbind(1 - y, y) : attempt to apply non-function
```

I realize this is a problem with having the `cbind` in my logit model.

Comment: What language is this ?

Comment: You should realize that some of us think it is _your_ responsiblity to  provide at the very minimum the name of packages with obscure functions. Some of us are even more picky and would not run this code unless you provided `dput(head(table.5.15))` and the library() command that loads the mystery package.

Comment: This was posted to another site where everyone seems to use R.  I don't know why it ended up over here.  I have no doubt some of you are very picky.  New here so thanks for the update.

Comment: It ended here because it's a "simple coding issue," which is explicitly off topic on the stats site.  On behalf of that site, I am grateful to the SO community for its suggestions and help in improving the question to meet your standards.

Comment: We statisticians would expect the same as far as rigor in presenting sufficient background. Nonetheless, the Hosmer Lemeshow test is pretty far removed from the basic statistics pedagogy. This is evidenced by the fact the it is not part of any standard package (that I'm aware of).

Answer (score 4):

Assuming you're using some implementation of the Hosmer Lemeshow test which roughly resembles [Frank Harrell's](http://www.stat.cmu.edu/~hseltman/files/hosmerlem.R),

it seems most likely that your mistake is a basic syntactical issue:

`miss.logit$cbind(Found,Missing)`,

Your `$` operator is not smart enough to reference both `Found` and `Missing` as objects which resolve in the scope of `miss.logit`. For instance:

```
> x <- data.frame('n'=1:26, 'l'=letters[1:26])
> x$cbind(n, l)
Error: attempt to apply non-function
```

The issue is that R thinks `cbind` is a function that lives in `x` which you're trying to evaluate on two globals `n` and `l`. Even if I made `cbind` an element of `x`, `n` and `l` would need to be referenced within `x` as well.

I can correct this code by using the with statement instead, or just basic array subsetting.

```
> x[, c('n', 'l')]     ## works (best)
> with(x, cbind(n, l)) ## works
> cbind(x$n, x$l)      ## works (worst)
```

Answer (score 2):

FYI for anyone else.
I'm an R newbie and I had a similar problem today...

My code:

> hosmerlem(y = MM_LOGIT$sick_or_not, yhat = fitted(MM_LOGIT))
>   Error in model.frame.default(formula = cbind(1 - y, y) ~ cutyhat) : 
>     variable lengths differ (found for 'cutyhat')

I had to change the y= bit to point towards the name of my data, rather than the logistic/glm output...

> hosmerlem(y=MYDATA$sick_or_not, yhat=fitted(MM_LOGIT))

```
$chisq
[1] 20.24864

$p.value
[1] 0.0003960473
```